# gsutil version -l lists 'compiled crcmod: False'

Tags: cloud, google-compute-engine, gsutil

When I run: `gsutil version -l` in my Win'2008R2 from the Google cloud SDK command prompt, I get:

```
checksum: 784a06805a228e6aa7d244e3477ccdca (OK)
boto version: 2.38.0
python version: 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:44:00) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
OS: Windows 2008ServerR2
multiprocessing available: False
using cloud sdk: True
config path: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\legacy_credentials\user@mail1.net\.boto
gsutil path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\gsutil
**compiled crcmod: False**
installed via package manager: False
editable install: False
```

I've installed a compiled version of Python 2.7 (x86 msi file) as per the instructions in `gsutil help crcmod` from:

```
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/crcmod/1.7 
crcmod-1.7.win32-py2.7.msi (md5)
MS Windows MSI installer    2.7     2010-07-20  128KB
```

That version of python installed it in `<python_dir>\files\Lib\site-packages\crcmod\` automatically, so I copied the `crcmod` folder to the recommended path: `<python_dir>\Lib\site-packages\crcmod\`

I've also added: `parallel_composite_upload_threshold = 150M` to my `.boto`

It still says `**compiled crcmod: False**`.

The `crcmod` installation info file says to run `python setup.py install`, though I'm not sure why if it's supposed to be compiled already? My installed version of `crcmod` doesn't even have this file, so I don't think I need to compile it.

I've also ran `python test.py` and it returns:

```
C:\python27_x86\files\Lib\site-packages\crcmod>python test.py
**Using extension: False**

.........
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 9 tests in 0.328s

OK
```

What am I missing? I'm able to upload files to my bucket using the `gsutil -o` command, but I'm not sure I'm getting the maximum performance if that says 'false'.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem. Silly me. I thought I had already installed Python 2.7 x86 but instead it was the x64 version. After installing Python 2.7 x86 and reinstalling crcmod for windows it now shows: compiled crcmod: True